# How to use ui:include with parameters?

Tags: jsf, parameters, include, reusability

Have JSF 1.2 two pages(one.xhtml and other.xhtml),
 that are included to the current page by following rule:

```
...
    <c:if test="#{flowScope.Bean.param1}">
        <ui:include src="one.xhtml"/>
    </c:if> 

    <c:if test="#{!flowScope.Bean.param1}">
        <ui:include src="other.xhtml"/>
    </c:if> 
...
```

As far `one.xhtml` differs from `other.xhtml` only by action parameters:

one.xhtml:`<h:commandLink action="actionOne">`
other.xhtml:`<h:commandLink action="actionTwo">`

Is it possible to use some general xhtml?
 Instead of one.xhtml and other.xhtml,something like this:

```
...
    <c:if test="#{flowScope.Bean.param1}">
        <ui:include src="general.xhtml" param="actionOne"/>
    </c:if> 

    <c:if test="#{!flowScope.Bean.param1}">
        <ui:include src="general.xhtml" param="actionTwo"/>
    </c:if> 
...
```

thank you for help.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You need to nest `<ui:param>` inside `<ui:include>` to pass parameters to the included file.

```
<ui:include src="general.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="action" value="actionOne" />
</ui:include>
```

and in the include:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{action}" />
```

Note that this only supports strings, not action methods. For the latter you would need to upgrade to JSF 2.0 and use [composite components](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html).

Comment: thanks, i khow about cc, they are great, but in current jsf 1.2 project can't use them.I will try your solution and write back about results.

Comment: It will work based on the way as you presented in the question. But if you were using `#{bean.doSomething}` instead of `actionOne`, you would really need to grab JSF 2.0 composite components.

Comment: strange, it throws: action="#{action}": Identity 'action' was null and was unable to invoke

Comment: As a note, param works with whole objects in addition to Strings.

Comment: @Adam: when using `<ui:param>`, yes. This is no secret. But this does not apply on `<f:param>` which will always be converted to `String`. Perhaps your initial confusion was based on this.

Comment: @BalusC: I was just looking to elaborate for future reference. Thanks for the note on `f:param` and its comparison to `ui:param`. I'd never used the `f` library version and will keep the difference in mind.

Answer (score 23):

In addition to BalusC's answer:

> Note that this only supports strings,
>   not action methods. For the latter you
>   would need to upgrade to JSF 2.0 and
>   use composite components.

There is a way to do this with JSF 1.2, though it's somewhat ugly:

```
<ui:include src="general.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="actionBean" value="#{myBackingBean}" />
    <ui:param name="actionMethod" value="edit" />
</ui:include>
```

and

```
<h:commandButton action="#{actionBean[actionMethod]}" />
```

Comment: May I know why for the actionBean value, we need to surround it with a #{} for it to work?